# command line STL volume tool

Tags: python, 3d

I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to check the volume of an object described by an [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29) file, on the command line, as simple as `$ ./check_volume file.stl`. These files can come in binary or ascii format, preferably the code would work for both.

I've done some googling and found a couple of tools, but [this one](https://github.com/mcanet/STL-Volume-Model-Calculator) has given me negative volume values, and [this one](https://github.com/nrs/stl-volume) openly admits:

> if you have holes in your volume, namely separate surfaces, the calculator may give unexpected results.

I could probably write something myself but I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me in the direction of an established, well-tested code that does this, or any python libraries which would make the job of coding this much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found something that seems like it fits the bill, https://sites.google.com/a/varlog.com/www/admesh-htm, seems to work nicely, reports volume in cubic mm.